# No data provided for "dense_Dense1_input"

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I have created a node project and trying to run the app but it is showing me following error:

Tried the different post but doesn't seems to be helpful in this case.

[image]

Here is the code-

```
private linearModel;
private nr_epochs = 1;
private tfinterface;
train() {
    console.log("Training model..");

    this.linearModel = tf.sequential();

    const xs = tf.tensor1d([8, 9, 12, 12, 15, 24, 24.5, 30, 35]);
    const ys = tf.tensor1d([1800, 2100, 2150, 3100, 3400, 6000, 6300, 7600, 8800]);

    // linear regression model
    this.linearModel.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
    // Prep for training
    this.linearModel.compile({ loss: "meanSquaredError", optimizer: "sgd", metrics: ["accuracy"], useBias: "true"});

    // train -- the higher the number the more accurate you'll get (but longer run time)
    this.tfinterface = this.linearModel.fit(xs, ys, { epochs: this.nr_epochs });

    console.log("Training completed");
}


    predict(val) {

    return this.tfinterface.then(() => {
        const output = this.linearModel.predict(tf.tensor2d([val], [1, 1]));
        const result = Array.from(output.dataSync())[0];
        //console.log(t);
        output.print();
        return result;
    });

}
```

Here is how the predict is called :

```
const routes = (app) => {
let model: LinearModel;
trainModel();
app.get("/v1/predict/:months", (req, res, next) => {
    model.predict(req.params.months).then((result) => {
        console.log("Going to predict for months : " + req.params.months);
        res.status(200);
        //res.write("Predicted: " + result);
        res.json(result);
        res.end();
    });
});
function trainModel() {
    model = new LinearModel();
    model.train();
}
};

module.exports = routes;
```

Comment: Could you provide the part where `predict()` is called? Or what val is?

Comment: sure, I have updated the question

Comment: Try `parseInt(req.params.months)` to parse it to a Number

Comment: tried that. Gives the same error

Comment: Could you add the value of `tf.tensor2d([val], [1, 1])`?, because the problem appears to be the x-data doesn't match the inputShape of the first layer

Comment: I tried changing it to tf.tensor1d([val]) so that they stay consistent with 1d, but still the same error.

Comment: try `const xs = tf.tensor2d([[8], [9], [12], [12], [15], [24], [24.5], [30], [35]]);` and the same for the ys

Comment: The issue was with typescript transpiler. When I remove typescript support seems to work fine.